# "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input > parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Getting the below error on build Asp.NetCore project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.6.0. The error goes sometimes if I restart visual studio. But I haven't got any proper solution.

> Error MSB4064 The "ComputeOutputOnly" parameter is not supported by
>   the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a
>   settable public instance property.    MyProject.Web.Public    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets    207 
>   Error MSB4063 The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input
>   parameters.   MyProject.Web.Public    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets    196

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue since it is a **[known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12527)** as mentioned above

- Close all instances of VS2017.
- Go to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.7\build folder using Windows Explorer.
- Rename the TypeScript.Tasks.dll to TypeScript.Tasks.dll.27 and Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to Microsoft.TypeScript.targets.27.
- Change 2.7 in the address bar to 2.4 to get to the equivalent folder for 2.4.
- Copy TypeScript.Tasks.dll and Microsoft.TypeScript.targets from there, press back and paste them in the 2.7 folder. Note that these are only the "Tasks" DLL and the targets file but not the actual compiler. The DLL must match the targets file.

It applies to typescript version 2.6 as well.

Should work Like a charm.

Comment: It felt kind of hackish but it worked.  I didn't have the problem until VS 2017 v15.6.7 so I don't know what @jaycer is talking about.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still getting this in 2020 with Visual Studio 2019. You need to restore your nuget packages, but first, you need to clear your global repository:

Close Visual Studio then PowerShell:

`dotnet nuget locals global-packages --clear`

Then delete/rename your packages folder inside your project folder.
Restart Visual Studio and do a NuGet Restore from VS as normal.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore for more info

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on build/clean when running multiple instances of `Visual Studio 15.9.3`. Solved when closing all instances and just opened Visual Studio again.

> The "ComputeOutputOnly" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc"
>   task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable
>   public instance property
>
> The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

However after starting and building a few times the following error occurred:

> The "TypeScript.Tasks.GenerateOutputLogs" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\Project\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2\build\..\tools\net45\TypeScript.Tasks.dll.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Tried to solve it by upgrading to `Visual Studio 15.9.6`. This worked for a while but then the errors came back.

Finally solved by running Visual Studio as **Administrator.**

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be resolved in Visual Studio 2017 v15.6.7 -- for me, this build error went away after upgrading.

Comment: Yes it’s fixed in VS

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22422. There is a reported workaround posted by Manish3177, but I have yet to try it myself to confirm it works.

EDIT:
I have tried the workaround and it did work for me. Manish3177 provided a good description of the cause. The temporary workaround unfortunately involves monkeying around with the Microsoft SDKs, copying v.2.4 task files up to the v.2.7 directory. Hopefully the Typescript team will have an official fix for this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by `installing/updating` latest the following `nuget packages from current project.

`TypeScript.MSBuildTask`,
`Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler` and

```
Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22422#issuecomment-373170515)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have TypeScript 2.6 in my VS 2015. I just uninstalled it and installed version 2.9.2 (which is latest at the time of this answer) and that fixed the issue for me.